# how to merge all forks of same repo by different user in github

Tags: git, github, git-fork

i am using gihub and created a private repo. where i have added few collaborators. they have created their own fork of my main repo. now they are working with their own fork by cloning it to their local pc. they are using git windows client to clone, commit, sync the repo. when they commit, the changes only visible to their own fork. but no one can see the changes by the commit from other collaborator of this repo. but every one needs to get the changes from other collaborator commit to their own fork. so how to merge all forks by different collaborators so that everyone can see everyone's changes? please help.

Comment: Why do you need a forked repo for each collaborator?

Comment: Pull their changes into the main repo.  Then anyone can pull from the main repo, and get all approved changes from other contributors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request). Take a look to [this](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) article, they explain how to do a pull request in Github.